# I want to keep the first toggle opened whenever the page opens. How can this be done?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I have tried to keep the first toggle open.

The first one should automatically be opened without clicking on the + symbol.

I tried implementing this by changing the code in javascript function.

I had changed the code to `.first().show()`

`!function(a){"use strict";a(".pafa-accordion-a").first().show()`

The above method opens all the toggle on page loading

This didn't work. Can someone guide me how to go about this?

Please find the inbuilt or existing code below:

```js
! function(a) {
  "use strict";
  a(".pafa-accordion-a").hide(), a(".pafa-accordion-q").click(function() {
    var b = a(this).hasClass("pafa-accordion-open"),
      c = a(".pressapps_faq_accordion").find("i." + icons.faq_open);
    a(".pafa-accordion-q").removeClass("pafa-accordion-open"), a(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(), c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close), b ? (a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(), a(this).removeClass("pafa-accordion-open")) : (a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideDown(), a(this).addClass("pafa-accordion-open"), a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))
  })
}(jQuery),
function(a) {
  "use strict";
  jQuery(".pafa-list-cat a, .pafa-list-q a, .pafa-back-top").each(function() {
    var b = "";
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
      var c = jQuery(this).attr("href"),
        d = a(this).parents(".pressapps_faq_list").find(c).offset();
      return b = d.top, jQuery("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: b - 30
      }, 500), !1
    })
  })
}(jQuery),
function(a) {
  "use strict";
  a(".pafa-block-a").hide(), a(".pafa-block").click(function() {
    var b = a(this).hasClass("pafa-block-open"),
      c = a(".pressapps_faq_block").find("i." + icons.faq_open);
    a(".pafa-block").removeClass("pafa-block-open"), c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close), a(".pafa-block-a").slideUp(), b ? (a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideUp(), a(this).removeClass("pafa-block-open")) : (a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideDown(), a(this).addClass("pafa-block-open"), a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))
  })
}(jQuery);
```

I had modified it with :

```js
! function(a) {
  "use strict";
  a(".pafa-accordion-a").first().show(), a(".pafa-accordion-q").click(function() {
    var b = a(this).hasClass("pafa-accordion-open"),
      c = a(".pressapps_faq_accordion").find("i." + icons.faq_open);
    a(".pafa-accordion-q").removeClass("pafa-accordion-open"), a(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(), c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close), b ? (a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(), a(this).removeClass("pafa-accordion-open")) : (a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideDown(), a(this).addClass("pafa-accordion-open"), a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))
  })
}(jQuery),
function(a) {
  "use strict";
  jQuery(".pafa-list-cat a, .pafa-list-q a, .pafa-back-top").each(function() {
    var b = "";
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
      var c = jQuery(this).attr("href"),
        d = a(this).parents(".pressapps_faq_list").find(c).offset();
      return b = d.top, jQuery("html,body").animate({
        scrollTop: b - 30
      }, 500), !1
    })
  })
}(jQuery),
function(a) {
  "use strict";
  a(".pafa-block-a").hide(), a(".pafa-block").click(function() {
    var b = a(this).hasClass("pafa-block-open"),
      c = a(".pressapps_faq_block").find("i." + icons.faq_open);
    a(".pafa-block").removeClass("pafa-block-open"), c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close), a(".pafa-block-a").slideUp(), b ? (a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideUp(), a(this).removeClass("pafa-block-open")) : (a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideDown(), a(this).addClass("pafa-block-open"), a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))
  })
}(jQuery);
```

HTML Code

```js
!function(a){"use strict";a(".pafa-accordion-a").hide(),a(".pafa-accordion-q").click(function(){var b=a(this).hasClass("pafa-accordion-open"),c=a(".pressapps_faq_accordion").find("i."+icons.faq_open);a(".pafa-accordion-q").removeClass("pafa-accordion-open"),a(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(),c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close),b?(a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideUp(),a(this).removeClass("pafa-accordion-open")):(a(this).parents(".pafa-accordion").first().find(".pafa-accordion-a").slideDown(),a(this).addClass("pafa-accordion-open"),a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict";jQuery(".pafa-list-cat a, .pafa-list-q a, .pafa-back-top").each(function(){var b="";jQuery(this).click(function(){var c=jQuery(this).attr("href"),d=a(this).parents(".pressapps_faq_list").find(c).offset();return b=d.top,jQuery("html,body").animate({scrollTop:b-30},500),!1})})}(jQuery),function(a){"use strict";a(".pafa-block-a").hide(),a(".pafa-block").click(function(){var b=a(this).hasClass("pafa-block-open"),c=a(".pressapps_faq_block").find("i."+icons.faq_open);a(".pafa-block").removeClass("pafa-block-open"),c.removeClass(icons.faq_open).addClass(icons.faq_close),a(".pafa-block-a").slideUp(),b?(a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideUp(),a(this).removeClass("pafa-block-open")):(a(this).find(".pafa-block-a").first().slideDown(),a(this).addClass("pafa-block-open"),a(this).find("i").removeClass(icons.faq_close).addClass(icons.faq_open))})}(jQuery);
```

```html
<div class="blog opened-article"><!-- Start Post Single Article -->
<article id="post-20047" class="cmsmasters_open_post post-20047 post type-post status-publish format-standard hentry category-school-of-aviation">
    <div class="cmsmasters_post_cont_info entry-meta"><div class="cmsmasters_data_author"><span class="cmsmasters_post_date"><abbr class="published" title="April 27, 2021">April 27, 2021</abbr><abbr class="dn date updated" title="May 6, 2021">May 6, 2021</abbr></span><span class="cmsmasters_post_author"><a href="http://vels.dupebox.com/author/adarsh-xtracut/" title="Posts by Adarsh" class="vcard author" rel="author"><span class="fn">Adarsh</span></a></span></div><span class="cmsmasters_post_category"><a href="http://vels.dupebox.com/category/school-of-aviation/" class="cmsmasters_cat_color cmsmasters_cat_134" rel="category tag">School of Aviation</a></span></div><header class="cmsmasters_post_header entry-header"><h2 class="cmsmasters_post_title entry-title">B.Sc Aviation</h2></header><div class="cmsmasters_post_content entry-content">
<!-- Accordion Template -->
<div class="pressapps_faq_accordion">
            <div class="pafa-accordion pafa-icon">
            <h3 class="pafa-accordion-q"><span style="background-color:#ef3737; border-radius: 0px; ?>;"><i class="si-add-2" style="color: #ffffff"></i></span>Course Outcomes</h3>
            <div class="pafa-accordion-a" style="display: none;">
                <b>PROGRAM EDUCATIONAL OBJECTIVES (PEO)</b><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PEO1:</strong> To help students to achieve deep knowledge of aviation stream we also aim to find, devolope and streamline the student’s interest in aviation and different aviation related field.&nbsp;</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PEO2:</strong> To develope skill to identify problem that may be hazardous to the safe operations of an aircraft in the quickest and safest possible manner and solving the problem within time constraint.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PEO3:</strong> To prepare a well trained&nbsp; and knowledgeable aviation personnel to cope up with ever devoloping aviation industry by frequently updating syllabus in accordance to the latest update in aviation field.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PEO4:</strong> To help students to work as a team to prevent, find or solve a situation together and encourages multi crew coordination (MCC) for efficient working with minimum error.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PEO5:</strong> Encourage and train students to be well groomed and prepare them to appear on radio telephony exam conducted by Ministry of communication, Govt of India to increase their scope of job opportunity</span><br><br>

<b>PROGRAM OUTCOME (PO)</b><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO1:</strong> Understand the role and responsibility of aviation personnel, having leadership quality to have a streamlined operation for the benifit of company.&nbsp;</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO2:</strong> Gain knowledge about safe operation of aircraft and finding the possibility which hinders the safety of aircraft operation.&nbsp;</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO3:</strong> Understand the flow and functions of various teams, working in an airport for smooth operation of aircraft and choosing the department of his own personal interest.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO4:</strong> Understand the restrictions, rules, the Do’s and Dont’s within an aerodrome area, to help the security executives to create a more safe air operations.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO5:</strong> Knows to work as a team in different sitiuation and handling the situation as a team and knows the value of multi crew coordination (MCC).</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO6:</strong> Have a clear idea about different documents and manual which are used by different department in aviation, the procedure to use and the process of updating it</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PO7:</strong> Have basic knowledge about aero medical, understands resource management, work load, stress management. Can judge various weather conditions, weather report, forecast and its effect.</span><br><br>

<b>PROGRAMME SPECIFIC OUTCOME (PSO)</b><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PSO1:</strong> Be well familiar with various department of aviation stream and have deep knowledge about their responsibilities and duties.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PSO2:</strong> Be competent in the field of aviation meteorology, air regulations, air navigations, aircraft technical, radio telephony</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PSO3:</strong> To adopt themself with the new technology which is devoloped to improve the safety, efficiency and streamlined flow of air traffic.&nbsp;</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PSO4:</strong> Well known about the importance of muti crew coordinaton (MCC), working and handling the situation as a team.</span><br><br>

<span style="font-weight: 400;"><strong>PSO5:</strong> Will be a professional aviation personnal who knows their roles and responsibilities in their concerned field and ability to grow in their field for the benifit of themself and aviation industry.</span><br><br>            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="pafa-accordion pafa-icon">
            <h3 class="pafa-accordion-q"><span style="background-color:#ef3737; border-radius: 0px; ?>;"><i class="si-add-2" style="color: #ffffff"></i></span>Eligibility Criteria</h3>
            <div class="pafa-accordion-a" style="display: none;">
                <p><a href="http://vels.dupebox.com/department-of-aviation-course-eligibility/"><strong>Click here to check your Eligibility</strong></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="pafa-accordion pafa-icon">
            <h3 class="pafa-accordion-q"><span style="background-color:#ef3737; border-radius: 0px; ?>;"><i class="si-add-2" style="color: #ffffff"></i></span>Fee Structure</h3>
            <div class="pafa-accordion-a" style="display: none;">
                <p><a href="http://vels.dupebox.com/department-of-aviation-fees-structure/"><strong>B.Sc Aviation Fee structure</strong></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
                <div class="pafa-accordion pafa-icon">
            <h3 class="pafa-accordion-q"><span style="background-color:#ef3737; border-radius: 0px; ?>;"><i class="si-add-2" style="color: #ffffff"></i></span>Subjects</h3>
            <div class="pafa-accordion-a" style="display: none;">
                <p><b>SEMESTER-1</b></p>
<p><b>FAMILIARIZATION OF AIRPORT</b></p>
<p><b>Course Objective: </b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">To acquire basic understanding of the layout of an Airport; its buildings, facilities, installations and their functioning.</span></p>
<p><b>UNIT 1: Buildings &amp; Installations&nbsp;</b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Terminals, Security, Apron, Hangar, Taxiway, Runway,Fire Station, Airport Vehicles, Fuel depot</span> <b>12</b></p>
<p><b>UNIT 2: Markings&amp; Lightings</b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">RWY &amp; TWY markings, Lightings, Signboards, Declared distances, PCN, Lighting system, Aerodrome Beacon, Obstacle Lighting &amp; Marking</span></p>
<p><b>UNIT 3: Facilities&amp;Equipments</b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">&nbsp;Navigational facilities:VOR, NDB, DME; Surveillance equipments:Primary Radar, SSR, Surface Movement Radar, ADS; GPS, VHF antennae, ILS</span></p>
<p><b>UNIT 4: Air Traffic Control</b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">ATC Units, Concept of FIR, Role of FIC, Roles of Tower &amp; SMC Controllers, Flight Plan, Flight Dispatch, ATC briefing</span></p>
<p><b>UNIT 5: Important Organizations</b></p>
<p><span style="font-weight: 400;">Ministry of Civil Aviation, ICAO, DGCA, AAI &amp; its wings, BCAS, CISF, MLU&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p>
<p><b>TOTAL&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 60Hrs</b></p>
<p><strong>Reference:</strong></p>
<ul>
<li aria-level="1"><b><span style="font-weight: 400;">ICAO Annex 14 Volume 1 Aerodrome Design and Operations</span></b></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li aria-level="1"><span style="font-weight: 400;">Civil Aviation Requirements Section-4, Aerodrome Standards &amp; Air Traffic Services.</span></li>
</ul>
<p><a href="http://vels.dupebox.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/B.Sc-Aviation-Syllabus-21.10.2016s.pdf" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer"><strong>VIEW ALL</strong></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>

</div><footer class="cmsmasters_post_footer entry-meta"><div class="cmsmasters_post_meta_info entry-meta"><span class="cmsmasters_likes cmsmasters_post_likes"><a href="#" onclick="cmsmastersLike(20047, false); return false;" id="cmsmastersLike-20047" class="cmsmastersLike cmsmasters_theme_icon_like"><span>0 </span></a></span></div></footer></article>
<!-- Finish Post Single Article -->
<aside class="post_nav"><span class="dn"></span></aside></div>
```

Comment: Can you give use a complete snippet with tools `<>` ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I had now edited the code with tools can you please check now

Comment: We need html too

Comment: We don't copy any code, can you please edit your code with html?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini, Sorry had added the HTML code too

Comment: You snippet doesn't work seems like incomplete and just copy from console google

Comment: This website developed in WordPress, all the js queries is calling by plugin, so that i had provided the site link itself - http://vels.dupebox.com/b-sc-aviation/

Comment: @SimoneRossaini can you please check and help me out

Comment: Why don't create a simple accordion instead of copy that? you can manipulate another one for the style no?

Comment: We had already created total upto 100 pages with same plugin now we need to open the first toggle

Comment: So can you create a working snippet so we can help you?

Answer (score 0):

I see you're loading jQuery on that site. What about using it to hit the first accordion item when loading?

Something like:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".pressapps_faq_accordion div:nth-child(1) span").click();
});
```

Ideally you'd edit the html so you have an id to grab onto and so you can more easily use this code elsewhere on the site, but I think it'll work anyway like this.

Comment: Sorry it didn't worked at all, the nth child and .first methods

Comment: That's weird. When I tried it on your site in console it worked fine. Did you get any errors? Where did you put the code?

Comment: So, loading that page and checking console, i don't see any pessapps.js file loaded. Why don't you try putting an html block in the page (near the bottom) and paste it in like this: 

<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".pressapps_faq_accordion div:nth-child(1) span").click();
});

</script>

Then it should work fine.

Comment: Yes by adding little tweaks, Thanks a lot